# jQuery Joyride and AngularJS Implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Any one have any experience implementing jQuery Joyride (http://zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin) with AngularJS?

I have followed the tutorial on Joyride's website, but it doesn't seem to work. I have read online that I might need to use a custom directive, but I'm not sure where to start.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Your question is a bit broad. You'd have to paste a sample of code you've built and point out where you're stuck to get good answers here.

Comment: Is it something like http://jsfiddle.net/mattymess/ZZH6P/

Comment: Here's an alternative: https://www.npmjs.org/package/ng-onboarding

Answer (score 4):

You probably already found this https://github.com/abhikmitra/ng-joyride. Abhik Mitra has already done all the work of wrapping into directives. Have been using it for last couple of days seems to work alright, I have found one bug with the 'title' templates and scoping but otherwise a pretty decent module.

Comment: Actually after working with it for a few days have decided to scrap it and write my own, too many issues getting to work in an angular app. Would be fine for a single static page, which is what joyride was originally written for but when you add in dynamic data it has too many issues.

Comment: Can you tell me what sort of issues you faced ?  I would be happy to fix all of that

Comment: Thank you that is a nice offer. The issues were primarily around dynamic data,if elements weren't in the DOM the module would break the UI trapping the user behind a curtain. Also we needed more control over highlighting and positioning as well felt it was better to decouple from the bootstrap popover. I forked the code and made some updates to work with our app, but in the end re-writing a version that accounts for dynamic steps, custom positioning, no bootstrap and location change is what we needed.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot publish the re-write as it is considered intellectual property of the company I work for, but you can always look into my [fork](https://github.com/simplesthing/ng-joyride) on github to see what kind of changes were made. - Cheers!

Comment: dynamic steps , and location change is now supported. No bootstrap version and custom positioning seem good features . Thanks for the ideas :)

Comment: @Abhik I want to implement this in my Ionic app.  I am new to Angular/Ionic programming and have been using npm to install modules.  Is there a specific trick or method to installing and implementing this into an Ionic app versus an straight Angular app?  Thanks!